# Deserialize multiple ArrayLists in a class using gson

Tags: arrays, gson

I have a class with multiple Lists. Is the class design correct for gson to work?

My class:

```
Class Data
{
    List<String> actor;
    List<Integer> text_relevance;
    List<String> title;
}
```

The json string is as follows ... 
Is the class design for this json correct?

```
{
    "data":
    {
        "actor":["Abercrombie, Ian","Baker, Dee Bradley","Burton, Corey",
                 "Eckstein, Ashley","Futterman, Nika","Kane, Tom",
                 "Lanter, Matt","Taber, Catherine","Taylor, James Arnold",
                 "Wood, Matthew"],
        "text_relevance":["308"],
        "title":["Star Wars: The Clone Wars"]
    }
}
```

Comment: text_relevance is not a Integer array, it is a string array as it has "" around the number.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your code is correct. I deserialized it with this code:

```
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, Data>>() {}.getType();
    Map<String, Data> map = gson.fromJson(json, type);
    Data data = map.get("data");
```

Note that Gson will convert strings like "308" to the corresponding integer. This is generally used to permit [very large values](http://blog.publicobject.com/2010/04/json-javascript-and-numeric-types.html) from losing precision. But it works out just fine for your case as well.

Comment: Should I not create a class for actor, text_relavence etc??